# Apache kafka Spring boot consumer not receiving topics when another consumer is running

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm quite new to Apache Kafka. I read a lot and I thought having understood the partitions and consumer groups mechanism. But I have an issue.

I have 2 spring boot projects. Both of them implement an apache kafka consumer.
For both of them the kafka parameters are defined in the application.properties file of each project. Following the common parameters:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

The 2 consumers belong to 2 different consumer groups. To achieve this goal I added a property in the application.properties file of each project. For the consumer 1 I defined the property:

```
kafka.consumer.group.id=GROUP.ID.SERVICE.ONE
```

For the consumer 2 I defined the property:

```
kafka.consumer.group.id=GROUP.ID.SERVICE.TWO
```

This way, in the service one I created a java class with the annotation @Service and defined the following kafka listener method:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${my.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group.id}", autoStartup = "true" )
public void consumeTopic(String kafkaMessage) {
//Do something      
}
```

For the service 2 I did the same:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${my.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group.id}", autoStartup = "true" )
public void consumeTopic(String kafkaMessage) {
//Do something      
}
```

There are no other applications belonging the same group of these consumers.
This way I was sure that both of them will receive the kafka message. But I was wrong: the application 2 does not receive the kafka topic if the application 1 is running (and it receives he topic). i performed a lot of tests and I can say that the application 2 receives the messages from kafka only if the application 1 is off.

What am I wrong? Further information: Apache kafka is installed on single node.